# Fetch Facebook posts which are liked by a profile(user/group/page)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to fetch all posts which are liked by a profile. Is there any api exposed for this ? Also, is there any way by which I can fetch new friends for a user or new people who have liked a page or new members of a group ?

Comment: fql tag removed - fql is deprecated and does not even work in newer apps anymore.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can only get liked Pages with `/me/likes` and the `user_likes` permission.
2. Getting "new friends" is not possible either, and of course you can´t get "new people who liked a page". You can only get that kind of information from users who authorized your App with `user_likes`. You can´t get any data of friends who did not authorize your App.
3. There is no API to get "new members of a group", you can only get all members with `/group-id/members` once in a while and check on your own.

Here´s a link to the API docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Comment: So, there is no way I can get posts which are liked by a user. Also, fetching new users is also not possible ? Is that correct ?